# Postgresql Using the Result set as values for querying

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I am trying to do is to aggregate all data from all of my tenants/users and from there make an SQL view. However the creation of Tenants is created dynamically but rest assured, all of their tables are the same.

What I am trying to do here is first get all the tenants in my database using this query.

```
select distinct table_schema 
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema','public')
and table_schema not like 'pg_toast%'
```

What I want to do is for each row, I'll do a union.

something like this

```
(SELECT * FROM tenant1.ref_product)
UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM tenant2.ref_product) 
UNION ALL(SELECT * FROM tenant3.ref_product)
```

is this possible?

Comment: I hope `table_schema` will returns  `tenant1,tenant2,tenant3`,right ??

Comment: @unique_id yup. it will return it.

Comment: just show table `ref_product`'s structure(create script) ???

Comment: the columns name and its type of table `ref_product`

Comment: But the tables are automatically generated by our ORM. no script. and your comment is out of the question. I was looking for answer that will allow me to loop the result set.

Comment: But in your Postgres database there will be a table called `ref_product` right >??

Comment: try [this](http://pastie.org/10069369)

Comment: @unique_id yes, but can you provide an example? I am getting confused.

Comment: I managed to get the String query. but how will I be able to execute it?

Comment: yes I will try ................

Comment: @unique_id tried using exec command but still did not work

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that in one command, you need first to execute one to build the `SELECT` statement you want, and the copy its result and execute it:

```
SELECT string_agg(
    format('(SELECT * FROM %I.ref_product)', nspname),
           ' UNION ALL ')
FROM pg_namespace
WHERE nspname !~ '^(pg_.*|information_schema|public)$';
```

Another option is to use PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE` command, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ref_product()
RETURNS SETOF tenant1.ref_product
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS $$
DECLARE
    v_cmd text;
BEGIN
    SELECT string_agg(
        format('(SELECT * FROM %I.ref_product)', nspname),
               ' UNION ALL ')
    INTO v_cmd
    FROM pg_namespace
    WHERE nspname !~ '^(pg_.*|information_schema|public)$'
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_cmd;
END;
$$;
```

At last, if you are using this often, consider create another schema (let's say "tenant_all") with the same table definition, and set all other table as child of it using PostgreSQL's `INHERTIS`. For example:

```
CREATE SCHEMA tenant_all;
CREATE TABLE tenant_all.ref_product(LIKE tenant1.ref_product);
ALTER TABLE tenant1.ref_product INHERIT (tenant_all.ref_product);
ALTER TABLE tenant2.ref_product INHERIT (tenant_all.ref_product);
ALTER TABLE tenant3.ref_product INHERIT (tenant_all.ref_product);
...
ALTER TABLE tenantN.ref_product INHERIT (tenant_all.ref_product);
```

So that way you can simple query `tennat_all.ref_product` and it will work exactly as if you are querying it one appended with `UNION ALL`.

Of course in all cases I'm assuming the tables schema matches perfectly.

Comment: On your third example. if there's new a product at tenant3. Will it immediately reflect tenant_all?

Comment: do the updates cascade? What I am trying to do is aggregate all data from different tenants into one view/source

Comment: @user962206, as I said it will work exactly as querying each one with `UNION ALL`. That is how inheritance work in PostgreSQL. When you query the parent (e.g. `FROM master`) is like having it and all children with appended (e.g. `FROM (SELECT * FROM ONLY(master) UNION ALL SELECT * FROM child1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM child2 ...) AS master`). So yes, any modification on "tenant*" will be visible by querying "tenant_all". Just make sure to do DDL changes on the "tenant_all" only, or at least to keep the changes in sync.

Comment: I tried running your command, the one that uses inheritance, it only displayed  CREATE TABLE tenant_all.ref_product(LIKE tenant.ref_product..) does not exist even if tenant1 exists,

Comment: @user962206, I'm **guessing** you meant `LIKE tenant1.ref_product ...`, see **tenant1** instead of **tenant**